# How can I always run an algorithm with standard input shapefiles from mapcanvas in QGIS 2.0.1?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, algorithm, data-model

I created a model in the graphical modeler and I want to run that model always with two specific polygon shapefiles from my project, e.g. `pst` and `astenot`. Whenever I run my model, it asks me to set the inputs from the list of shapefiles that are in my MapCanvas. To be more specific, I always want `vectorlayer_1='pst'` and `vectorlayer_2='astenot'`.

This is the script from my model. Can anyone tell me how I can do that? I'm wondering if there is a way to do that directly in graphical modeler.

```
##difference_between_pst/astenot=name
##vectorlayer_1=vector
##vectorlayer_2=vector
##output_alg0=output vector
##output_alg1=output vector
##output_layer_alg2=output vector
##output_layer_alg3=output vector
outputs_0=Processing.runalg("qgis:difference", vectorlayer_1, vectorlayer_2, output_alg0)
outputs_1=Processing.runalg("qgis:difference", vectorlayer_2, vectorlayer_1, output_alg1)
outputs_2=Processing.runalg("qgis:saveselectedfeatures", outputs_0['OUTPUT'], output_layer_alg2)
outputs_3=Processing.runalg("qgis:saveselectedfeatures", outputs_1['OUTPUT'], output_layer_alg3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change you script in:

```py
##difference_between_pst/astenot=name
##output_alg0=output vector
##output_alg1=output vector
##output_layer_alg2=output vector
##output_layer_alg3=output vector
vectorlayer_1 = "pst"
vectorlayer_2 = "astenot"
outputs_0=Processing.runalg("qgis:difference", vectorlayer_1, vectorlayer_2,   output_alg0)
outputs_1=Processing.runalg("qgis:difference", vectorlayer_2, vectorlayer_1,  output_alg1)
outputs_2=Processing.runalg("qgis:saveselectedfeatures", outputs_0['OUTPUT'], output_layer_alg2)
outputs_3=Processing.runalg("qgis:saveselectedfeatures", outputs_1['OUTPUT'], output_layer_alg3)
```

[image]

Comment: It came up with an error :name 'Processing' is not defined.

Comment: In QGIS 2.0, it is `processing`, in QGIS master, it is `Processing`

Comment: After changing Processing with processing, another error came up : name 'vectorlayer_1' is not defined.

Comment: I found this :map = QgsMapCanavs() ,                                                      
layer = QgsVectoryLayer('path.shp','myshapefile','ogr'),
map.setLayerSet([layer]), to create a script that opens a layer in a map canvas (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29580/how-to-run-a-simple-python-script-for-qgis-from-outside-e-g-sublime-text). But i don't know how to use it in the code. It would be helpful if you have any idea. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Maybe it's working only from python console and not from script editor?

Comment: Sorry, no problem for me

Comment: I found what's missing!@gene Your changes in the script were absolutely right. It additionally wants: ##vectorlayer_1=input vector, ##vectorlayer_2=input vector, and the script run perfectly. But for some reason after the changes, I can’t see it in user scripts (Processing Toolbox, it is saved in the same correct folder). Do you have any idea about that?