# Select by location in Python

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I have a polygon layer and a point layer (with coordinates for each point).
The polygon layer got created using the MMQGIS plugin (Hexagonal Polygons). 
I want to select all the points inside each polygon.

I worked with ArcGIS before but I want to change to open source. 
Furthermore, I want to approach that through a Python script since I want to analyse the extracted data. I have QGIS 2.8 installed. I am a bit overwhelmed by all the GIS libraries there are for Python.

Can I approach that sort of selection with a GIS library that is already installed with QGIS? If so, could anyone pin point me into the right direction?

Comment: Related question and answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256569/select-features-from-another-layer-based-on-a-selection-in-pyqgis

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you want to run your script within QGIS (from a script file or Python console), you can use the following:

```
import processing

processing.runalg("qgis:selectbylocation", INPUT, INTERSECT, METHOD, OUTPUT)
```

Here is the help description provided by the Python console which defines each parameter:

```
processing.alghelp("qgis:selectbylocation")
ALGORITHM: Select by location
    INPUT <ParameterVector>
    INTERSECT <ParameterVector>
    METHOD <ParameterSelection>
    OUTPUT <OutputVector>

METHOD(Modify current selection by)
    0 - creating new selection
    1 - adding to current selection
    2 - removing from current selection
```

To create a script entirely from scratch which doesn't call on QGIS functions, the following links might help in developing similar functionality:

- [From Processing plugin](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/SelectByLocation.py)
- [From fTools plugin](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/fTools/tools/doSelectByLocation.py)

---

**EDIT**:

There are a couple of posts which might be of some use with writing scripts outside QGIS for Mac:

- [How to run a simple python script for QGIS from outside (e.g. Sublime Text)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29580/how-to-run-a-simple-python-script-for-qgis-from-outside-e-g-sublime-text)
- [Fixing Python path for QGIS scripting on Mac OSX](http://carlosgrohmann.com/blog/fixing-python-path-for-qgis-scripting-on-mac-osx/)

Comment: Hello Joseph. Thanks for your reply. I want to use QGis functions! But I think I do not want to make that in the QGis console but call a script from the console of my computer (OS X 10.10). Which library are you using there? Or which library is QGis providing and how can I access that API? Is there anything to read on that?

Comment: No problem Stophface! I've edited my post to include links which describe how to use scripts outside QGIS for Mac. I use Windows :) In terms of scripting, I don't think there's much difference, the biggest being setting the PATHS I think (I'm also a beginner!).

Comment: Yes, that path setting is something which wont work over here at all. But once thats fixed, it will save a lot of work later on :) Is there a documentation on the library QGis is using? That way I do not have to come back here but just look things there up. Is it PyQGis?

Comment: Yes, it uses [PyQGIS](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html) :)

Comment: Most welcome buddy!

Answer (score 4):

Joseph's answer is correct, although there needs to be another parameter included: "PREDICATE".

ie:

```
processing.run("qgis:selectbylocation", {
    "INPUT":lyr_input,\
    "PREDICATE":0,\
    "INTERSECT":lyr_intersect,\
    "METHOD":0,\
    "OUTPUT":path}
)
```

From `processing.algorithmHelp("qgis:selecybylocation")`:

```
PREDICATE: Where the features (geometric predicate)

    Parameter type: QgsProcessingParameterEnum

    Available values:
        - 0: intersect
        - 1: contain
        - 2: disjoint
        - 3: equal
        - 4: touch
        - 5: overlap
        - 6: are within
        - 7: cross

    Accepted data types:
        - int
        - str: as string representation of int, e.g. '1'
        - QgsProperty
```