# Selecting items in the attribute column based on items of another layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, attribute-table, fields-attributes, select-by-attribute

I have the items in my data attribute table, which were selected. I want to make the object with the same value be selected in the attribute table, which belongs to another layer. In both cases, the considered column is called `"new_name"`.

If for instance the `"new_name"` value has been selected in the left attribute table I need exactly the same value to be selected in the other attribute table.

[image]

How can I make a selection such as this?

Comment: I do remember. When everyone needs to wait for confirmation, I am not returning to the problem for a longer time. Sorry for making you frustrated. I do appreciate your answer and reward it right now. Thank you for being so helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can suggest a PyQGIS solution.

Proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor` and paste the script below

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject

layer1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Final cellsites')[0]
layer2 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Lighting columns')[0]

field1 = "new_name"
field2 = "new_name"

selected_features = [feat[field1] for feat in layer1.selectedFeatures()]

selected_attributes = f'({selected_features[0]})' if len(selected_features) == 1 else tuple(selected_features)

expression = f'"{field2}" in {selected_attributes}'

layer2.selectByExpression(expression)
```

Press `Run script` [image: run script] and get the output that will look like

[image: example]

---

**References:**

- [How to create a tuple with only one element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876177/how-to-create-a-tuple-with-only-one-element)
- [Selecting features using expression with PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131158/selecting-features-using-expression-with-pyqgis)
- [Getting attributes of selected features using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31799/getting-attributes-of-selected-features-using-pyqgis)
- [Select features from another layer based on a selection in PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256569/select-features-from-another-layer-based-on-a-selection-in-pyqgis)
- [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/index.html#pyqgis-developer-cookbook)

Answer (score 8):

You can use this expression in select by expression of layer2:

```
array_contains(
  aggregate(
    'layer1',
    'array_agg',
    "new_name",
    is_selected(
      'layer1',
      $currentfeature
    )
  ),
"new_name")
```

What it does:

`aggregate()` returns an array of of all `new_name` values of `layer1`. Using the `filter:=is_selected('layer1',$currentfeature)` it will only return those `new_name` values, which are currently selected in `layer1`. `array_contains()` then checks if the current `new_name` value of `layer2` is in that array. If yes, it selects the feature.

Comment: No matching features found. However no error appear, which means we are nearly there

Comment: @MKR make sure that you have features selected in layer1, execute this expression in layer2 and that both layers have the exact same attributes (take care of whitespaces and stuff like that) as well as the same fieldtypes. Dont forget to rename layernames and fieldnames to the ones you actually use. If it still does not work for you, feel free to share some example data.