# Running Python outside of QGIS - (ImportError: No module named qgis.core)

Tags: qgis, python, windows, eclipse

I'm trying to run simple scripts on QGIS from *outside* the QGIS environment - as here

[How to run a simple python script for QGIS from outside (e.g. Sublime Text)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29580/how-to-run-a-simple-python-script-for-qgis-from-outside-e-g-sublime-text)

**My code:**

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\QGISBrighton\\apps\\Python27")
import qgis.core
```

**My output:**

```
ImportError: No module named qgis.core
```

My qgis_core.dll is at

> C:\Program Files (x86)\QGISBrighton\apps\qgis\bin

QGIS install is here:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\QGISBrighton

**In Control Panel > System > Advanced**

PYTHONPATH set to

> C:\Program Files (x86)\QGISBrighton\apps\Python27

Path set to

> C:\Python27; C:\Program Files (x86)\QGISBrighton\apps\Python27; C:\Program Files (x86)\QGISBrighton\apps\qgis\bin

I've tried multiple permutations of setting my Path, PYTHONPATH and appending to sys.path on the fly (as detailed in many answers here).

I'm hoping by providing the above information someone can give me explicit instructions on how to get past

> ImportError: No module names qgis.core

Comment: Try following [some of the answers](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129915/cannot-run-standalone-qgis-script/130304#130304) provided by @gcarrillo who has helped a great deal in solving similar issues.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph! @ben-mayo: Specifically, I suggest you to follow the steps given at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129959/problem-with-import-qgis-core-when-writing-a-stand-alone-pyqgis-script/130102#130102.

Comment: I had this problem. The solution for me was to re-install QGIS following the 'Advanced Install' instructions here: http://spatialgalaxy.net/2014/10/09/a-quick-guide-to-getting-started-with-pyqgis-on-windows/

Specifically: From the Select packages screen, select the following for installation:
Desktop -> qgis: QGIS Desktop
Libs -> qt4-devel (needed for lrelease/translations)
Libs -> setuptools (needed for installing pip)

Answer (score 6):

This solution worked for me in Windows 7x64 SP1 with `Python 2.7.13-64bit` and `QGIS 2.14.9x64` standalone install (**important**: Python and QGIS architectures **must match**). This solution involves `virtualenv` ([install instructions](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/)) which means you won't need to play with Python environment variables which can be tricky if you're doing other Python development with different versions of Python.

### Editing Path

Edit the PATH variable by going to `Control Panel>System>Advanced system settings` then click on `Environment Variables` in the below window.

[image: Advanced system settings]

Edit the **PATH** User Variable and add `;C:\Program Files\QGIS Essen\bin\;C:\Program Files\QGIS Essen\apps\qgis-ltr\bin`, note the version `Essen` as well as the use of `qgis-ltr\bin` here. The latter **was necessary** in order for Python to be able to find the `qgis_core.dll`.

### Create a Virtual Environment

Create a new virtual environment in the command line: `virtualenv qgisenv -p "C:\path\to\Python27.exe"` specifying the `Python 2.7` location. Note this will create a folder for your virtual environment, you should put any projects you develop in here.

Next add paths to the installed QGIS python libraries to the virtual environment's `site-packages` folder using [`.pth` files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10739838/4047679). For example in `QGIS 2.14.9` python packages can be found at the following locations (why?), so create a file `qgisenv\Lib\site-packages\qgis.pth` with:

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS Essen\apps\qgis-ltr\python
C:\Program Files\QGIS Essen\apps\Python27\
C:\Program Files\QGIS Essen\apps\Python27\Lib\
C:\Program Files\QGIS Essen\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages
C:\Program Files\QGIS Essen\bin
C:\Program Files\QGIS Essen\include
C:\Program Files\QGIS Essen\apps\qgis-ltr\bin
```

*this list can probably be shortened*

### Activate Environment and Test

Back in the Command Prompt `cd` into the `qgisenv` directory and activate the virtual environment with `Scripts\activate`

Then open a `python` console and type

```
>>> from qgis.core import *
```

And you should be good to go!

### How to use an IDE?

If you use anaconda and Spyder, you could use `conda` to set up the environment and then call `spyder` after activating the environment. Other IDEs might have the option of setting a virtual environment from the settings.

Comment: If you are using the virtualenv to set up qgis why then do you have to manually edit the system PATH variable. Shouldn't virtualenv take care of that for you?

Comment: @user32882 I'm not setting up QGIS in a virtualenv, I'm instead setting up a separate virtualenv to work on a PyQGIS project.