# Create link for open specific object in the project map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, excel, hyperlink

I am working to link Excel and QGIS. Is it pssible to create a link that can be put in Excel and when cklicked open the map/project zoomed to the specific object?

Greets

Comment: You may need to write script to the QGIS API to control the active layer and zoom of QGIS - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29580/how-to-run-a-simple-python-script-for-qgis-from-outside-e-g-sublime-text