# Piping custom processing algorithm output into another in QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, algorithm, qgis-3

I am using QGIS 3.0.

Following up on [Calling a QgsProcessingAlgorithm from a Processing python script in QGIS 3.0?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278834), I am writing a `Processing` python script based on the template provided [here](https://anitagraser.com/2018/03/25/processing-script-template-for-qgis3/).

It takes a few additional parameters in addition to the `'INPUT'` and `'OUTPUT'` from the template. I am using these parameters to create some lines and everything works out fine.

Now I need to call a `Processing` Algorithm, namely `qgis:clip` to clip the lines I just created according to the Polygon entered as `'INPUT'`.

Is there a way to pipe my output into `qgis:clip` ? Or do I need to create a temporary layer that I will then feed into `qgis:clip` and let it's `'OUTPUT'` become mine ?

Either way, I'm not sure where to start.

I've tried defining a `QgsFeatureSink` or a `QgsProcessingFeatureSink` but the first is an abstract thingy and the second just won't be recognized (I can't even import it from `qgis.core`)

I've seen [Using processing using other output (result from another algorithm) as input](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132315) and [Import error for qgis.core when running OSGeo4w shell script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129915) but I couldn't figure out a working solution to my problem so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this is not what I wanted to do, the easiest way to do this is to use the `Model`.
This way it is easy to plug the output from one Algorithm to the input of another one.