# Piping output of one processing algorithm as input into another algorithm in QGIS Processing script?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-2.18

I created a processing script in QGIS 2.18 that connects two processing algorithms (first **clip** and than **dissolve**). The output vector from the **clip** is supposed to be an input into the **dissolve**.

The code of my processing script is provided here:

```
##input_layer=vector
##clip_layer=vector
##clipped_layer=output vector
##processed_layer=output vector

clip_area = processing.runalg("qgis:clip", input_layer, clip_layer, 
clipped_layer)

fin_area = processing.runalg("qgis:dissolve", clip_area, "true", None, 
processed_layer)
```

The screeshot of processing script UI when I try to run it is below:

[image: UI of processing script]

Both of the algorithms work correctly standalone, but when I try to pipe them it does not work as intended. I only get *clipped_layer* as output and the following error notification in Python Console:

[image]

There are several questions adressing related issues like [Pipe custom processing algorithm output into another in QGIS 3.0](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278893/pipe-custom-processing-algorithm-output-into-another-in-qgis-3-0) but none really answers my question.

Does anybody know how to correctly pipe algorithms in the example processing script provided above?

I know it could be solved by using Processing Modeler but since I plan to expand the script further, please, don´t suggest this as solution.

Comment: Try using `fin_area = processing.runalg("qgis:dissolve", clip_area['OUTPUT'], "true", None, processed_layer)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The processing.runalg() return a python dictionary with one record: 'OUTPUT' is the key and the value is the absolute path at result layer.

So in the next algorithm instead of the parameter `clip_area` you have to use `clip_area['OUTPUT']`

Comment: Yes, you need to specify the 'OUTPUT' with the output layer. This worked for me. Thanks

Does this work for all kind of algorithms with spatial outputs?

Comment: Sometimes changes the key string value `'OUTPUT'`, you have to print the dictionary result to know it... Take care that all of this is heavily changed in QGIS 3.0