# Memorizing temporary layer from processing.runalg() in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, qgis-processing, algorithm

I created some geoalgorithms with QGIS and I need to use them in a Python script. By saving the layer obtained in a file having a specific path, I do not have problems.

For example:

```py
processing.runalg("modeler:esplodilinee", "buildings", "C:\prova\sides.shp") 
lines = iface.addVectorLayer("C:\prova\sides.shp", "poligon sides", "ogr")
```

But I would not use a file, but rather a temporary variable, in order to re-use it within the specific script.
The description of the algorithm suggests to me that:

```py
ALGORITHM: esplodilinee 
buildings <ParameterVector> 
OUTPUT_ALGQGISEXPLODELINES_1 <OutputVector>
```

So, I thought to do something like this:

```py
OUTPUT_ALGQGISEXPLODELINES_1 = processing.runalg("modeler:esplodilinee"
"buildings", None)
lines = processing.getObject(OUTPUT_ALGQGISEXPLODELINES_1)
```

But I get a mistake and not the desired results. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct to set the last parameter as `None`, so you create a .shp inside a temporary folder.

**To get it**: as you can see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280254/pipe-output-of-one-processing-algorithm-as-input-into-another-algorithm-in-qgis/) the output of processing.runalg is a python dictionary.

So in your last code example you have to write `OUTPUT_ALGQGISEXPLODELINES_1['OUTPUT']` instead of `OUTPUT_ALGQGISEXPLODELINES_1` to get the path at the temporary layer.

The documentation is [here](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html) and quite well written.

Comment: Thank you a lot.
Unfortunately I didn't solve the problem.

If I correct my code as follow:

OUTPUT_ALGQGISEXPLODELINES_1= processing.runalg ("modeler: esplodilinee", "buildings", None)
lines = processing.getObjectFromUri(OUTPUT_ALGQGISEXPLODELINES_1['OUTPUT'])

I get an error: "TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' ".
Do you suggest me why?
Thanks again.

Comment: The processing.runalg() doesn't work and return a None object...
1) `buildings` is a QgsVectorLayer object?

2) Your model is working well outside the script? The input parameter is only one?

Comment: 1)yes, it is a polygon layer.
2) the model works well outside the script and also when I fix a specific filepath (as in my first example)

Comment: I edited my previous comment

Comment: Me too :) I would notice you that the error is linked to code line "lines = processing.getObjectFromUri(OUTPUT_ALGQGISEXPLODELINES_1['OUTPUT'])" and not to the model.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work because `OUTPUT_ALGQGISEXPLODELINES_1` isn't a dictionary but a None Type object. This because the runalg isn't working.... Try to run in the QGIS python console only the processing.runalg(...) untill it works :)

Comment: I found the error! :) I wrote a space between ":" and "esplodilinee".
Now it works!

prova=processing.runalg ("modeler:esplodilinee", buildings, None)
lines = processing.getObject(prova['OUTPUT_ALGQGISEXPLODELINES_1'])

Thank you so much!

Comment: Well done :). If you find useful any of my aswer or comments please upvote them. I really appreciate it