# Using memory layer as input with processing runalg in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, algorithm, memory-layer

My first processing runalg creates a memory layer as output.
I need to use this layer as the input for the second runalg.

```py
#first
processing.run("qgis:fieldcalculator", {
    'INPUT': 'test_1_f08f5cd1_13ea_445b_9778_6ee0ab919030',
    'FIELD_NAME': '1.3-field',
    'FIELD_TYPE': 0,
    'FIELD_LENGTH': 10,
    'FIELD_PRECISION': 3,
    'NEW_FIELD': True,
    'FORMULA': '((length(shortest_line(centroid($geometry),boundary($geometry)))))*1.3',
    'OUTPUT': 'memory:'
    })

#second
    processing.run("qgis:fieldcalculator", {
    'INPUT':?????,
    'FIELD_NAME': '1.3-field',
    'FIELD_TYPE': 0,
    'FIELD_LENGTH': 10,
    'FIELD_PRECISION': 3,
    'NEW_FIELD': True,
    'FORMULA': '((length(shortest_line(centroid($geometry),boundary($geometry)))))*1.3',
    'OUTPUT': 'memory:'
    })
```

I have found this links but none could help me.

- [Using memory layer as input and/or output with runalg?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183479/using-memory-layer-as-input-and-or-output-with-runalg/206800)
- [Using processing using other output (result from another algorithm) as input](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132315/using-processing-using-other-output-result-from-another-algorithm-as-input)

Comment: See [PyQGIS 101: Chaining Processing Tools](https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis101-chaining-processing-tools/)

Answer (score 0):

I have chained processing algorithms within a processing script by adding the output of the first algorithm to a sink (see underdark's tutorial) then using dest_id1 (for example) as the input for the next processing script.  I found that it was necessary to add the line del sink between uses of the sink and to declare `OUTPUT1 = "OUTPUT_1"` and `OUTPUT2 = "OUTPUT_2"` at the start of the script and the syntax at the end that worked for me was:

```
results = {}
results[self.OUTPUT1] = dest_id1
results[self.OUTPUT2] = dest_id2
return results
```

All other syntax to do with outputs has to be duplicated.