# fTool in pyqgis: Is it possible?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, loop

I am doing a work which I need to sample random points for many layers (classification of land use). Then, I'm trying to do a loop with my several layers and applied a functions of random pointos. I would like to use Random Points... functions (tool that I find in Menu>>Vector>>Research Tools>> Random Poits) because there I would choose 20 points pet class. This tool allows to make this.

It function (Random points...) belongs to fTools plugin, however I didn't find it functions in python console. All information that I saw in internet wasn't help me (or I couldn't understand).

How can I put this tool (Random points...) in my script? Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use tools from Processing framework in PyQGIS. I think the tool you need from fTools is already in Processing, and it's called "Random points in layer bounds."

Just follow the same logic explained in [Cannot run standalone QGIS script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/130304/4972) for running a Processing algorithm in PyQGIS. You'll need to call the tool like this:

```
general.runalg('qgis:randompointsinlayerbounds', vector, point_number, min_distance, output)
```

and pass the proper parameters:

- vector: a polygon layer.
- point_number: default 1.
- minimum_distance: default 0.0
- output: path to the output layer (e.g., '/tmp/output.shp').

Hope it helps.

Comment: This function that you advised to me doen't work how I want. My sample design is stratified, and I would like randomized 20 points per class. The problem is that only possibility in "Random points in layer bounds" is randomized number of sample points for all extension of layer.