# Minidump Error Messages With Large Dataset

Tags: qgis, large-datasets

I'm using QGIS 2.8 on a system running Windows 8.1 (x64) with 12GB of RAM. I am attempting to run analyses of a very large database (.gdb format, 7.17GB).

In attempting to run the "Join attributes by location" function on two vector layers, I get an error message of a minidump to C (i.e, "minidump written to C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\qgis-20150717-131933-1872-4788-1b929ef.dmp"). This also occurs when attempting to run "Intersect" on these two layers.

Restarting the computer hasn't fixed this issue, nor has updating all my plugins. I looked into changing the name of the .qgis2web folder ([as recommended at http://hub.qgis.org/](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/12867)), but that didn't work.

Using a similar, but smaller database (also .gdb format, but only 5MB) these functions work fine. This makes me thing the issue has something to do with the size of the dataset.

Anyone have any experience with this issue?

Comment: Perhaps you could look into using a standalone script outside of QGIS to use the **Join attributes by location** tool rather than running it inside QGIS. An advantage of this is that it frees up more RAM which may be a cause for your minidump error. The answers provided by @gcarrillo greatly helped me in this post [Cannot run standalone QGIS script](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129915/cannot-run-standalone-qgis-script).