# Can't run processing.algrun() in external Python application

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I am trying to create an external Python application. I want to run this as a stand alone program in command line. I am trying to not use the QGIS console.

A first step is to clip a point shapefile using a polygon shapefile.

When I try to use `processing.runalg("saga:clippointswithpolygons",...)` nothing happens. There are no error messages or warnings. Nothing is written to the output shapefile.

```
import sys
import urllib

import pathlib

from qgis.core import QgsApplication
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer
from qgis.core import QgsVectorFileWriter

# Constants
node_shape_path = r'C:\Temp\TMC_nodes.shp'
clip_path = r'C:\Temp\clip.shp'  # Path to clipping polygon
out_shapefile_path = r"C:\Temp\TMC_Nodes_Clipped_2.shp"

##
# Prepare the QGIS environment and framework
##

# Prepare the QGIS environment
qgis_prefix = u'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISPI~1/apps/qgis'
app = QgsApplication([], True)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(qgis_prefix, True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# Prepare the QGIS processing framework
sys.path.append(plugins_path)
#from processing.core.Processing import Processing
import processing

##
# Clip the nodes and write to a new shapefile
##
processing.runalg("saga:clippointswithpolygons", node_shape_path, clip_path, "OBJECTID", 0, out_shapefile_path)
```

I have tried different versions of the `processing.runalg` line where I use file path strings instead of layers. I even went so far as to take the point layer, made from the csv, write it to a shapefile, and then use that path.

I have used the processing toolbox GUI to successfully conduct the clip. The log file reads:

```
ALGORITHM|Mon Sep 21 2015 12:26:24|
processing.runalg("saga:clippointswithpolygons","C:/Temp/TMC_nodes.shp","C:/Temp/FCMS_clip.shp","OBJECTID",0,"C:/Temp/TMC_Nodes_Clipped.shp")
```

I have even tried pasting the command call from the log directly into my external script, but it still does not work.

Comment: Try using double brackets for the full path or for the directory which contains the shapefile. Eg. `node_shape_path = r'C:\\Temp\\TMC_nodes.shp` or `node_shape_path = r'C:\Temp\\TMC_nodes.shp`. (As a side, I never used the raw string variable `r` when setting paths for external applications but might not work for everyone!).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is possible as processing requires iface, which is not created in standalone applications:

http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8955

Comment: +1 for mentioning the problem which occured initially but you can now use _Processing_ for direct paths to files instead of from `iface` :). I asked a [similar question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129915/cannot-run-standalone-qgis-script) a while ago.