# How to know if your script is executed in a QGis python console or a standard python console?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-python-console

Is there any way to detect if a script is computed on QGIS python console or not?

Any attribute or test to assess it?

Comment: Isn't this just a dupilcate of your previous question? [Is my script executed from a QGIS plugin or from a standard python console? Conditional Imports](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177581/is-my-script-executed-from-a-qgis-plugin-or-from-a-standard-python-console-cond)

Comment: This one is more general, but I'll edit the other one to be distinct, you're right. Both can be useful for different use cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You sure can.

```
import qgis.utils
inqgis = qgis.utils.iface is not None
```

In QGIS this will return `True` outside it will return `False`

Comment: I found also : 
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
QSettings()
returns an error outside QGIS, ty both of you!

Comment: basing on QSettings is not a correct solution... you script can be executed in a QApplication that is not qgis and it will return the appliaciton conf

Answer (score 2):

I didn't check, try this:

A) from qgis.utils import iface

- can generate importError exception in case not initQgis with correct prefix => outside qgis!

B) iface.mainWindow() == None

- if not error in A => you can be in a qgis standalone app => then you verify if a mainwindow has been ininitialized

giev us a feedbak

Comment: ok... I didn't check that iface is None... tnx @nathan