# Executing a voronoi polygon to a shapefile With Pycharm

Tags: shapefile, pyqgis, pycharm

I'm trying to get a voronoi polygon from points using Pycharm. 
I've tried:

```
processing.runalg("qgis:voronoipolygons", file ,1, "C:\Voronoi.shp" )
```

but it doesn't work. It works in the python console in QGIS but not in Pycharm .

This is my code:

```
import shapefile

import ProcessingLog
import processing
import sys
from sets import Set

from qgis.core import QGis, QgsFeatureRequest, QgsFeature, QgsGeometry, QgsPoint

from processing.core.GeoAlgorithm import GeoAlgorithm
from processing.core.GeoAlgorithmExecutionException import GeoAlgorithmExecutionException
from processing.core.parameters import ParameterVector
from processing.core.parameters import ParameterNumber
from processing.core.outputs import OutputVector
import voronoi
from processing.gui.SilentProgress import SilentProgress
from processing.tools import dataobjects, vector

def runalg(alg, progress=None):

  if progress is None:
      progress = SilentProgress()
  try:
      alg.execute(progress)
      return True
  except GeoAlgorithmExecutionException as e:
      ProcessingLog.addToLog(sys.exc_info()[0], ProcessingLog.LOG_ERROR)
      progress.error(e.msg)
      return False


file = "C:\Armoire.shp"
r = shapefile.Reader("C:\Armoire.shp")
processing.runalg("qgis:voronoipolygons", file ,1, "C:\Voronoi.shp" )
```

The error is:

> QPixmap: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [How to set conditional imports for a PyQGis script running inner or outer of QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177581/how-to-set-conditional-imports-for-a-pyqgis-script-running-inner-or-outer-of-qgi)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for my problem .
There is the code:

```
from qgis.core import *


# supply path to qgis install location
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\\Program Files\\QGIS Lyon\\apps\\qgis", True)

# create a reference to the QgsApplication, setting the
# second argument to False disables the GUI
qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
# load providers
qgs.initQgis()

# Write your code here to load some layers, use processing algorithms, etc.


layerInput = QgsVectorLayer("C:/shape.shp", "test", "ogr")


if not layerInput.isValid():
  print "Layer failed to load!"
else:
    print "Layer was loaded successfully!"

from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()

Processing.runAlgorithm("qgis:voronoipolygons", None, layerInput,1, "C:/tmp.shp")

# When your script is complete, call exitQgis() to remove the provider and
# layer registries from memory
qgs.exitQgis()
```