# Use QGIS API on standalone python program without install the entire application

Tags: qgis, python, api, standalone

I developed a standalone python program that makes use of QGIS API to create .qml files from sld files. This is a small program of about 15 lines of code that imports the following modules and uses few methods such as `loadSldStyle` and `saveNamedStyle`.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
```

Is there any way to avoid the installation of all QGIS application and install just the necessary modules, if I want to run a standalone python program that makes use of a simple QGIS functionality?

It seems to be too much install an entire application just to use 2 or 3 functions...

Comment: What specific function of PyQGIS did you use ? .qml files are simply XML files and there are many modules in Python to process XML files, shapefiles and... without the need of QGIS

Comment: What I do in my program is to add an SLD file to a shapefile, and save the corresponding style as a .qml file. A similar one is written here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188131/export-qml-file-using-qgis-api#answer-188133. How would you do this without the need of QGIS?