# No Module named qgis

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, python-2.7, osgeo4w

I installed QGIS through OSGeo4W, and I am trying to write a standalone PyQGIS script, however, I am unable to import the qgis, qgis.core, processing ect… modules, as shown in the picture, I get the ‘Import Error: No Module named qgis...

[image]

I sought help from the many examples that exist that require you to change your command line path to your python libraries, change your python path to your c:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\python ect…

Here is a list of the answers I tried, but, it seems myself and many others are still unable to fix this issue, as I could not get it to acknowledge the existence of those libraries:

[Problem with import qgis.core when writing a stand-alone PyQGIS script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129959/problem-with-import-qgis-core-when-writing-a-stand-alone-pyqgis-script):

[Cannot run standalone QGIS script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129915/cannot-run-standalone-qgis-script?lq=1)

[Running Custom Applications:](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am running a batch file first.

```
call "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\o4w_env.bat"
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\bin
```

Comment: Fantastic you found your own solution, am sure this will help others

Comment: I tried to use this method as it is much easier than mine, but, I still get Import error: No Module named QGIS @okorkut

Comment: Have you verified the path of the "o4w_env.bat" in your computer. I set this according to my path. I assumed that since you installed through QSGeo4W file paths should be similar. May be your file installed in a different directory.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I solved the issue, it’s a bit of work, but you can now import the modules without hassle,
I created a Python Script, that uses the module subprocess, to write an osgeo4w command called ‘python-qgis’ 
Its nothing complicated, here it is
[image]

I called it NotePadPlus.py (No real reason for calling it that)
I then call this script from the osgeo4w command shell

[image]

And now I am able to call the qgis module without any issue! And just to show its not just pretending to accept it I misspelled the Tkinter module and it says it does not exist
 [image]

I hope this helps, and you can adapt it to suit your needs!

Comment: Couldn't you just call `python-qgis` from the osgeo4w shell (whithout the python subprocess wrapper script)?

Comment: yes you can! what I have done is created an entire python script that does various tasks, and at the start the subprocess calls the python-qgis, and this then allows the qgis and other modules to be called in the rest of that same script

Answer (score 1):

Here is probably the best solution I have found, it has made very easy thanks to http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/running_qgis_jobs.html.

First thing you need to do is create a batch file, call it "launch", and enter the following
[image]

Then you create your GIS Standalone Python script, hopefully, this is more complex than mine, but this is just to show you that the modules import correctly.

[image]

Then all you need to do is trigger the launch batch file( I just double clicked mine) and it will import the modules without issue!

[image]