# No module name Processing

Tags: python, pyqgis

I want to create a standalone pyQGIS script in python editor but I have importing error on Processing

```
import sys
from qgis.core import *
sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins')
import Processing
```

I turn for similar question and all suggestion import path for Processing plugins and I add this path and I have error again.
How to fix that on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2):

This [Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200510/no-module-named-qgis) contains a variety of answers that assisted me when I was building a standalone PyQGIS script and repeatedly had the error no module named *qgis* and no module named *processing*.

The answer I used is the one discussing the .bat file that triggers the standalone and connects to the processing toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

The module is called `processing` in small letters

```
import processing
```

or

```
from processing import Processing
```

Also have a look at this complete example and excellent answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/131809/9839

Comment: yes but if i want to import `processing` algorithm show me error `Error: Algorithm not found` for ex algorith `outputs_SAGASLOPEASPECTCURVATURE_1=processing.runalg('saga:slopeaspectcurvature', dem,6,1,1,slope,aspect,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None`

Comment: Have you initialized processing? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131764/run-processing-toolbox-outside-qgis-in-standalone-app

Comment: yes i have i can see in QGIS and in QGIS folder,and `from processing import Processing` not work

Comment: Can you confirm: the code snippet from this answer does not work for you: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/131809/9839

Comment: i dont understand

Comment: Open the link in my last comment, copy and paste the code there and check if this also produces an error.

Comment: i have do that, now dont show anythink not error not print,why ?

Comment: not work again if i add line `SAGASLOPEASPECTCURVATURE_1=processing.runalg('saga:s‌​lopeaspectcurvature'‌​, dem,6,1,1,slope,aspect,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,No‌​ne,None,None)` and define inputs and outputs not work again dont show me anythink

Comment: I would recommend to open a new question as per the site policy of "one question per post"