# qgis_process run script from command line

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, command-line

qgis_process allows us to run scripts already installed in QGIS from the command line. But is there a way to run qgis scripts *not* yet installed?

e.g. if I have a file `script.py`

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
# (...etc...)
class Foo(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    # defines my algorithm, which works fine in qgis
```

Can qgis_process or some other tool run this from the command line without me having to add `script.py` to the toolbox in qgis first?

The command-line help to qgis_process is encouraging in that it says

> (...) run     runs an algorithm. The algorithm id or a path to a model
> file and parameter values must be specified. Parameter values are
> specified via the --PARAMETER=VALUE syntax

But if I provide a path to `script.py` (with or without the `.py`) it says not found.

Comment: It sounds like you want to run a python script that calls QGIS processing outside of a QGIS Python window.  See this link for help:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200510/no-module-named-qgis