# Use QGIS with script only without opening QGIS first

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2.14, idle

I would like to use the QGIS algorithms without opening QGIS.

I would like to use a script to automate processing with a Windows computer from IDLE (python GUI).

Comment: There are a number of [posts](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bqgis%5d%20standalone%20script) which describe how to run standalone scripts. Especially this [question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129915/cannot-run-standalone-qgis-script) I asked a while ago where @GermánCarrillo solution worked. Note that it describes running the script from **OSGeo4W Shell** and not from _IDLE_.